# Авторизация через curl

Tags: curl, php, авторизация

Здравствуйте.

Нужна помощь. Как получить ссылку на профиль при авторизации curl steam?

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd"> 
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" dir="ltr" lang="ru"> 
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Заголовок</title></head>
<?php 
$usereagent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; ru; rv:1.9.0.8) Gecko/2009032609 Firefox/3.0.8)";
function post_content($url, $postdata) {
global $usereagent;
$ch = curl_init($url);
$root_directory = dirname(__FILE__);
$cookie_file = $root_directory."/coo.txt";
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_ENCODING, "");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $usereagent);  // useragent
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 120);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postdata);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR,  $cookie_file);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $cookie_file);
$content = curl_exec($ch);
$err = curl_errno($ch);
$errmsg = curl_error($ch);
$header = curl_getinfo($ch);
curl_close($ch);
$header['errno']   = $err;
$header['errmsg']  = $errmsg;
$header['content'] = $content;
return $header;
}

//Login in steam
//$get_url = 'https://steamcommunity.com';
$username = '***';
$passwd = '***';
$postdate = array('action'    => doLogin, 
        'goto'       => '', 
        'steamAccountName'      => $username,
        'steamPassword'    => $passwd,
        'x'    => 23,
        'y'    => 11,); 
$result = post_content('https://steamcommunity.com/?action=doLogout', $postdata);
echo $result;
var_dump($url);
var_dump($postdate);
?>
```

Comment: @Сергей Румянцев, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 1):

Быть может, дело в том, что в URI ты передаешь параметр `?action=doLogout`, а в данных POST — `action=doLogin` (кстати, `doLogin` взять бы в кавычки)? Кто его знает, в каком порядке они обрабатывают параметры.

Кроме того у меня лично часто случались проблемы с файлами cookie — они то не создавались, то криво перезаписывались: один раз куки сохранились, следующая страница пыталась дописать что-то в куки, но сломала весь файл. После того как файл оказывался побит, куки больше не читались и не писались в этот файл.

Советую промониторить весь процесс авторизации в реальной обстановке ручкам в консоли Хрома на вкладке Network. Очень сомнительно выглядят параметры `x` и `y`.

Answer (score 0):

Так не получится. )

У стима есть API, используйте их, а лучше уже готовые скрипты есть для авторизации на стиме.

Comment: Не мне нужно, зная логин пароль, поймать ссылку профиля.

Comment: @Сергей Румянцев, это ж стим, вход возможен только через WinAPI, ) поэтому сначала вход, а там в API ты спокойно получишь ссылку на профиль.

Comment: @Manitikyl

> вход возможен только через WinAPI

что, простите?